# How can I sum cumulatively values on condition in polars or pandas? [with example]

Tags: pandas, python-polars

I have a problem i'm trying to solve using preferably polars but pandas is also fine.
Say we have the following dataset (sample):

```py
{
  "date" : [2022-01-01, 2022-01-02, 2022-01-03, 2022-01-04, 2022-01-05],
  "customers" : [3, 4, 5, 3, 2],
  "is_reporting_day?" : [True, False, False, False, True]
}
```

to make it a bit clearer, here's a table format

| date | customers | is_reporting_day? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | True |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 | False |
| 2022-01-03 | 5 | False |
| 2022-01-04 | 3 | False |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | True |

What i want to get is: if `reporting_day is True` keep the customers number as is, and if the `reporting_day is False` I want to sum up all the customers (4, 5, 3 = 12 + 2 = 14) and add it to the next `True value reporting day`

so after applying the transformation it should look like this:

| date | customers | is_reporting_day? | customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | True | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | True | 14 |

I've tried to use the the `cumsum()` function in polars by using the `pl.when` statement but it's the incorrect logic since it sums up from the beginning, i.e., the first day (there are about 700 days).

**Note: the solution should be dynamic, i.e., sometimes the gap between a reporting_day and non-reporting_day is 1 day, 2 days, etc.**

Any ideas or input is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach the problem is to create groups based on the `is_reporting_day?` column.

If we take the `date` when it is *True*

```py
df.select(
   pl.when("is_reporting_day?").then(pl.col("date"))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date       │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ 2022-01-05 │
└────────────┘
```

We can then [`.backward_fill()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.backward_fill.html) the `date` to include the previous *False* rows.

```py
date = pl.when("is_reporting_day?").then(pl.col("date"))

(df.group_by(date.backward_fill(), maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.all().last(),
      pl.sum("customers").suffix("_sum")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ date       ┆ customers ┆ is_reporting_day? ┆ customers_sum │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---               ┆ ---           │
│ date       ┆ i64       ┆ bool              ┆ i64           │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 3         ┆ true              ┆ 3             │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2         ┆ true              ┆ 14            │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i've tried to achieve. indeed looks very similar to mozway's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are already sorted, use a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (df.groupby(df['is_reporting_day?'].shift(fill_value=False).cumsum(), as_index=False)
         .agg({'date': 'max', 'customers': 'sum', 'is_reporting_day?': 'max'})
      )
```

Output:

```
         date  customers  is_reporting_day?
0  2022-01-01          3               True
1  2022-01-05         14               True
```

If you need both the initial and sum of "customers":

```
out = (df.groupby(df['is_reporting_day?'].shift(fill_value=False).cumsum(), as_index=False)
         .agg(**{'date': ('date', 'max'),
                 'customers': ('customers', 'last'),
                 'is_reporting_day?': ('is_reporting_day?', 'max'),
                 'customers_sum': ('customers', 'sum'),
                })
      )
```

Output:

```
         date  customers  is_reporting_day?  customers_sum
0  2022-01-01          3               True              3
1  2022-01-05          2               True             14
```

Alternative:

```
out = (
 df.assign(date=df['date'].where(df['is_reporting_day?']).bfill())
   .groupby('date', as_index=False)
         .agg(**{'date': ('date', 'max'),
                 'customers': ('customers', 'last'),
                 'is_reporting_day?': ('is_reporting_day?', 'max'),
                 'customers_sum': ('customers', 'sum'),
                })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
col1=(df1.is_reporting_day.eq(False)&df1.is_reporting_day.shift().eq(True)).cumsum()

df1.groupby(col1,group_keys=False).apply(lambda dd:dd.tail(1)
                                         .assign(customers2=dd['customers'].sum()))
```

out:

```
    date  customers  is_reporting_day  customers2
0  2022-01-01          3              True           3
4  2022-01-05          2              True          14
```